# PHP Session lost after redirect (sometimes)

Tags: apache-http-server, php, redirection, session

I use, Apache/2.4.28 (Win64) PHP/7.0.32 in a Windows environment.

I try to do with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242346/php-session-lost-after-redirect), but in my case, a lost error occurs sometimes.

(Sometimes mean, problem occur 5 hours or more hours or few days...)

(I think, maybe.. this PHP problem https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=16263)

(This, very similar case, but don't have solution... https://serverfault.com/questions/869781/apache-on-windows-cookie-w-php-sessions-bug)

When I try to save session and redirect, sometimes it fail.

//Normal case

1. session_start() -> get session id from server 'aaa' -> save in cookie
2. redirect with 'aaa' cookie in request header
3. I can use session in redirect page.

//Error case

1. session_start() -> get session id from server 'aaa' -> save in cookie
2. redirect with 'aaa' cookie in request header
3. but server response different session id 'bbb'. Even web-server has 'sess_aaa' file on Windows temp folder. In this case, server has 'sess_aaa' and 'sess_bbb' two session files.

   - sess_aaa : have session information.
   - sess_bbb : 0kb empty session file
4. I can not use session until apache restart.

//More information about this error...

- Windows resource CPU 3~5%, Memory 30% -> no problem
- $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, $_SERVER other PHP variables works well.

Please help me with your good idea.(Thanks for Hastur's guide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change Windows PHP to FCGI version...(Non Thread Safe)
Then works well.